# Insert into master table when detail records present but missing master

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - one master, one detail (i.e. a one-to-many pair of tables). I'm importing data from a horrible schema and one feature of the data is that often I have some detail records but no master.

How would go about inserting master records in these cases? I can locate the missing masters easily enough with this query:

```
select * from p_ltx_surgical_comp as c -- detail
left join p_ltx_surgical as s -- master
on c.fk_oid = s.fk_oid -- this is the key
where s.oid is null -- primary key, so null means no record exists
group by c.fk_oid; -- only show one value even if there are multiple detail records
```

Oh, and as an extra wrinkle, I only want to insert a single master even if there a are multiple detail records.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with this INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO p_ltx_surgical (fk_oid)
SELECT DISTINCT c.fk_oid
FROM
  p_ltx_surgical_comp AS c
  LEFT JOIN p_ltx_surgical AS s
  ON c.fk_oid = s.fk_oid
WHERE
  s.oid IS NULL
```

and you can add more details to your table, for example:

```
INSERT INTO p_ltx_surgical (fk_oid, description, ...)
SELECT DISTINCT c.fk_oid, 'missing record', ...
FROM
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks - I got to the pretty much the same thing. I think my numb-skullery was based on my thinking that I wouldn't be allowed to update a table that was listed in the select.

Comment: hey can you tell me from where did sp_getvdtablekey came from ?

Comment: It's just a stored function we use in our application to increment a non-incrementing primary key (we ran into some problems with the native mysql increment).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was so close... this seems to have worked:

```
insert into p_ltx_surgical (oid, fk_oid, ltx_surg_date)
select sp_getvdtablekey('p_ltx_surgical', 0), c.fk_oid, '1900-01-01' from
p_ltx_surgical_comp as c -- detail
left join p_ltx_surgical as s -- master
on c.fk_oid = s.fk_oid -- this is the key
where s.oid is null
group by c.fk_oid; -- primary key, so null means no record exists
```

Comment: i didnt get from where sp_getvdtablekey came from ??

Comment: is it the function you have created ??

Comment: code lover, yes. It's a pretty basic function but I'm more than happy to let you have it (I tried adding it to this thread, but it says it's too long).